# How to create link to same component in stencil?

Tags: stenciljs

Given url `localhost:8080/resource/1` and configured route:

```
<stencil-route url="/resource/:id" component="my-resource" />
```

When I click a link link:

```
<stencil-route-link url='/resource/2'>Resource 2</stencil-route-link>
```

Then URL location changes and component doesn't reload. What can I do in that case?

Comment: Do you have an `id` prop on the component?

Comment: I use MatchResults - https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-router/wiki/Passing-data-to-routes
I tried @Prop but it doesn't bind anything. This is not documented so I guess it is not supported?

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment, I was thinking of `ion-router`. I just tested it with the app starter and the component is rerendered because `@Prop() match` changes. Does `@Watch('match')` fire in your app when you change the URL?